# Jasmine test of angular directive is failing because inner directive is not getting compiled. Why not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my directive:

```
//Since angular-ui-switch only works for booleans, if you have 0/1 int field, you can use
//this directive (which is just a wrapper around angular-ui-switch) to model the field.
//Use as <int-switch></int-switch>

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hntb-utils')
        .directive('intSwitch', intSwitch);

    intSwitch.$inject = ['$compile'];

    function intSwitch($compile) {
        return {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                model: "=ngModel",
                on: '@?',
                off: '@?'
            }
        };

        function link(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.boolModel = scope.model ? true : false; //{ value: scope.model ? true : false };

            activate();

            function activate() {
                scope.$watch('boolModel', convertToInt);

                scope.on = scope.on || 'On';
                scope.off = scope.off || 'Off';

                var html = '<switch ng-model="boolModel" on="' + scope.on + '" off="' +
                scope.off + '" class="' + attributes.class + '"></switch>';

                element.html(html).show();
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }

            function convertToInt(value) {
                if (arguments.length)
                    scope.model = value ? 1 : 0;
                return scope.model ? true : false;
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

Basically as mentioned in the comment this is a wrapper for angular-ui-switch.

Now the test:

```
describe('directive - intSwitch', function () {

    var intSwitchScope,
        intSwitchEl,
        switchEl,
        switchScope;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('hntb-utils');

        inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {

            intSwitchScope = $rootScope.$new();
            intSwitchScope.model = false;

            intSwitchEl = $compile('<int-switch ng-model="model"></int-switch>')(intSwitchScope);
            intSwitchScope.$digest();

            switchEl = intSwitchEl.find('switch');
            switchScope = angular.element(switchEl).scope();

        });
    });

    it("Check that ui-switch has been built and is working.", function () {

        var test = switchEl.children();
        switchEl.children()[0].click();
        intSwitchScope.$digest();
        expect(switchScope && switchScope.boolModel == true).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("Should track boolean model value and replace integers.", function () {

        expect(intSwitchScope.model == 1).toBeTruthy();
        switchEl.children()[0].click();
        intSwitchScope.$digest();
        expect(intSwitchScope.model == 0).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

The test is failing at: `switchEl.children()[0].click();` because switchEl does not have any children. The angular-ui-switch directive looks like:

```
angular.module('uiSwitch', [])

.directive('switch', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE'
  , replace: true
  , transclude: true
  , template: function(element, attrs) {
      var html = '';
      html += '<span';
      html +=   ' class="switch' + (attrs.class ? ' ' + attrs.class : '') + '"';
      html +=   attrs.ngModel ? ' ng-click="' + attrs.disabled + ' ? ' + attrs.ngModel + ' : ' + attrs.ngModel + '=!' + attrs.ngModel + (attrs.ngChange ? '; ' + attrs.ngChange + '()"' : '"') : '';
      html +=   ' ng-class="{ checked:' + attrs.ngModel + ', disabled:' + attrs.disabled + ' }"';
      html +=   '>';
      html +=   '<small></small>';
      html +=   '<input type="checkbox"';
      html +=     attrs.id ? ' id="' + attrs.id + '"' : '';
      html +=     attrs.name ? ' name="' + attrs.name + '"' : '';
      html +=     attrs.ngModel ? ' ng-model="' + attrs.ngModel + '"' : '';
      html +=     ' style="display:none" />';
      html +=     '<span class="switch-text">'; /*adding new container for switch text*/
      html +=     attrs.on ? '<span class="on">'+attrs.on+'</span>' : ''; /*switch text on value set by user in directive html markup*/
      html +=     attrs.off ? '<span class="off">'+attrs.off + '</span>' : ' ';  /*switch text off value set by user in directive html markup*/
      html += '</span>';
      return html;
    }
  }
});
```

I placed a break point inside ui-switch's template function and it looks like it is not getting executed. I expected it to be compiled when I compiled my directive. I placed a breakpoint at `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` in int-switch's linking function, and it is executing. Why is the inner directive not compiling?

Comment: This is a ton of spaghetti code, with a lot of anti-pattern sauce. I'd suggest you write this in a more conventional way and with better practices, and then come back. You may find that it's easier to debug for yourself, and it certainly will be for us.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Can you expand on that? I would like to rewrite appropriately just don't know what is wrong...

Comment: I'll try, though it'll be hard to fit what fundamentally should be different into comments.

Comment: 1. Don't compile HTML if you can help it. Occasionally you'll be working with an API that you don't control, and you need to use the HTML it returns, but otherwise you should only provide HTML to a directive/controller by providing a template property, or a templateUrl property.

2. Don't use jQuery with Angular. It's a problematic crutch that often defeats the purpose of using Angular at all.

3. Provide dependencies with [inline array notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation). This unambiguously guarantees what you're working with.

Continued in next comment...

Comment: 4. For anything more than the most trivial templates, create a static HTML file and reference it. Having a long, fragmented string like you have for the template of `switch` to represent your view means that whatever text editor you're working in isn't helping you to structure and develop your layout. Additionally, the way you programmatically assemble your template just seems pointless. The whole point of Angular is that you can give a static template that will bend itself to your data.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Are your comments directed at the second directive (third block of code)? If so, that is not my directive, it is angular-ui's switch directive. My directive has a one-line template which I didn't think was worth putting in its own file. In terms of using JQuery, I agree with you in principle. However, there is a reason the element comes in as JQLite wrapped element. I don't think its unreasonable to use a couple of functions that are native to it.

Comment: Ah, my mistake in regards to `switch`. If it's a part of the framework that's designated as a generic DOM manipulator, it's fine, and reduces how severe this is. Still, That only clears the bit about referencing an external HTML file. Most everything else still holds.